# Using ArrayAdapter and tag. Null Pointer exception

Tags: android

Now I am developing android apps. I have a serious problem that I think... The program is died by Null Pointer exception. But, I don't understand " Why is the program died ". Here is my source code.

```
class CommentViewHolder{
    NetworkImageView userIcon;
    TextView userName;
    TextView timeAgo;
    TextView deleteBtn;
    TextView comment;
}
public class CommentsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Comment> implements OnClickListener{

    private Context mContext;
    Comment comment;
    CommentViewHolder holder;

    public CommentsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Comment> object){
        super(context,0,object);
        mContext = context;
        holder = null;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

        View v = convertView;

        if ( v == null ){
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.detail_comment_listview, null);

            holder = new CommentViewHolder();

            holder.userIcon = (NetworkImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.detailCommentUserIcon);
            holder.userName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.detailCommentUserName);
            holder.timeAgo = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.detailCommentTimeAgo);
            holder.deleteBtn = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.detailCommentDeleteBtn);
            holder.comment = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.detailComment);

            v.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (CommentViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        comment = this.getItem(position);
        holder.userName.setTag(comment);   // here I set the tag!

        if( comment != null ){

            holder.userName.setText(comment.getUserName());
            holder.timeAgo.setText(comment.getTimeAgo());
                holder.deleteBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.deleteBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            holder.comment.setText(comment.getDescription());

            holder.deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
            holder.userName.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Comment clickItem = (Comment)v.getTag();
        int userId = clickItem.getUserId();  // Null Pointer exception this line...
        int commentId = clickItem.getId();

        switch(v.getId()){

        case R.id.detailCommentUserName:
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), userId + "id", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;  

        case R.id.detailCommentDeleteBtn:
            Uri.Builder uri = null;
            Log.d("Bucket",commentId +"");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

And... When I click the R.id.detailCommentUserName button, then the program act widget Toast message. BUT! When I click detailCommentDeleteBtn then the program is died because of Null Pointer exception.

Please give me advices...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your OnClick is getting the deleteBtn passed as the parameter View v, and looking at the tag of the *button*. But your adapter is setting the tag on the convertView (in the main branch of the if), and the userName textfield (below the if). You need to set the tag on the deleteBtn.

Comment: Thank you, RobP. I set a tag for deleteBtn and solve this problem!